# Why list.append() in Python changes every item in the original list?

Tags: python, arrays, json

I have this piece of code:

```
import json

a = '''
{
    "c": {
        "d": [
            {
                "e": "f"
            }
        ]
    }
}
'''
j = json.loads(a)
l = []

for n in range(20):
    if n % 2 == 0:
        j['c']['d'][0]['e'] = n
        l.append(j)
        
print(l)
```

The output of this code:

```
[{'c': {'d': [{'e': 18}]}}, {'c': {'d': [{'e': 18}]}}, {'c': {'d': [{'e': 18}]}}, {'c': {'d': [{'e': 18}]}}, {'c': {'d': [{'e': 18}]}}, {'c': {'d': [{'e': 18}]}}, {'c': {'d': [{'e': 18}]}}, {'c': {'d': [{'e': 18}]}}, {'c': {'d': [{'e': 18}]}}, {'c': {'d': [{'e': 18}]}}]
```

The output I was expected:

```
[{'c': {'d': [{'e': 0}]}}, {'c': {'d': [{'e': 2}]}}, {'c': {'d': [{'e': 4}]}}, {'c': {'d': [{'e': 6}]}}, {'c': {'d': [{'e': 8}]}}, {'c': {'d': [{'e': 10}]}}, {'c': {'d': [{'e': 12}]}}, {'c': {'d': [{'e': 14}]}}, {'c': {'d': [{'e': 16}]}}, {'c': {'d': [{'e': 18}]}}]
```

How to get the expected output?

Comment: You're repeatedly altering the same dictionary inside `j` and adding `j` to your list. You're not copying `j` anywhere.

Comment: You are changing the same dictionary and repeatedly adding it to the list. Every item in the list points to the same python object. Thus, the end result will be the list with identical objects and not what you expected. You need to make a copy and then add a copy to the list as proposed by the solutions below. To better understand how this works, please read this guide: https://realpython.com/python-pass-by-reference/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you modify `j` and subsequently append it to the `l`, it's a reference to the same dict that you append.  Here is one way to operate on copies:

```
import copy
import json

a = '''
{
    "c": {
        "d": [
            {
                "e": "f"
            }
        ]
    }
}
'''
j = json.loads(a)
l = []
for n in range(10):
    j2 = copy.deepcopy(j)
    j2['c']['d'][0]['e'] = 2 * n
    l.append(j2)
        
print(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you append to the list `l` are identical dictionary. To avoid this, try this.

```py
import json
import copy

a = '''
{
    "c": {
        "d": [
            {
                "e": "f"
            }
        ]
    }
}
'''
j = json.loads(a)
l = []

for n in range(20):
    if n % 2 == 0:
        j['c']['d'][0]['e'] = n
        l.append(copy.deepcopy(j))

print(l)
```

[FYI](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html)

Comment: Thank you for the link, I should study more on this..

Comment: You change `j` before making a copy which mean `j` is modified.  Its alright but making a copy before to a new name is probably least surprising.